# Centering three icons on screen for webpage

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve the following configuration of elements for a webpage:

[Left Icon Image]<-padding->[Horizontally Centered Icon Image]<-padding->[Right Icon Image]

Each icon has some text below it which is centered relative to it's own center What is the best way to achieve this using HTML and CSS?

Comment: Please let us see your code. A fiddle is good.

Comment: You should really try to do it yourself before posting here as well as include your code in your question.

Comment: let me see your code, so I can help you

Comment: Check out my answer, should have everything you need. And like I said, there are many ways to do it. That's just one.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post any code so normally I wouldn't help but since this isn't that hard and there are **many** ways to do this I will show you one.

### HTML:

```
<div id="con">
    <div>
        <img src="http://www.psdgraphics.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/danger-icon.jpg" /> 
        <span>Text under the first one</span>

    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://www.psdgraphics.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/danger-icon.jpg" /> 
        <span>Test under the second</span>

    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://www.psdgraphics.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/danger-icon.jpg" /> 
        <span>And third</span>

    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
#con {
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#con div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
#con div img {
    width: 200px;
}
```

So here we create 3 "boxes" that will contain each image with text. We set the `width` and `height` then use `float`. Now we need to put them in a container so we can center them using `margin: 0 auto;`.

From there it's just get the image you want in the boxes and type your text under it. I put a `span` so you can see where it is a bit better + you can style it using the `span`.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/bvLkK/)

---

Here is one with a `margin` around each so they push away from eachother. Don't want to use padding as that's inside the element (I guess you could but margin would be better).

### CSS:

```
#con {
    width: 660px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#con div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
```

We added a `margin` to `#con div` and then have to change the `#con` width to account for the newly added `60px` caused by the margin.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/bvLkK/1/)